# Composer download Drush 9 - But conflict errors

Tags: drush

I just installed drush 7 and 8 in their own directory under /usr/bin as drush7, drush8 commands. Now I'm trying to do the same for drush9, but I'm getting a conflict error during the composer download of drush 9. How can I resolve this to only download the 9.x version?

The command I used was: **composer require drush/drush:9.***

I got this idea of using all the drush versions from:

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/switching-drush-versions

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you request `composer require drush/drush:9.*`, you are telling Composer that you want the latest **stable** release of Drush on the 9.x branch.  However, Composer considers dev, alpha, beta and even RC releases to be unstable.  These releases can be downloaded in one of two two ways:

1. Create a composer.json file, manually add the release designation you want (e.g. 9.*), set the `minimum stability` to dev or alpha, or some other applicable value, and then run `composer install` (or `composer update`, if you already have a composer.lock file).
2. Explicitly request the version you want -- e.g. `composer require drush/drush:9.0.0-alpha1`, or ``composer require drush/drush:dev-master`.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was just download the master branch:

**composer require drush/drush:dev-master**

The master branch contained the latest drush version which is 9 as of today. But I'm still unsure how you can pick 9.x. Or how do you list out which branches you can select from.